# Call method from main thread function

Tags: python, multithreading, class, methods

I've a thread class and when I get a message I need to call other method (outside class). How I can make it?

```
class ClientThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        ...
        message = asdasd.sdas
        outside(message)
        ...

def outside(m):
     ...
```

When I try to call I've a error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
NameError: global name 'outside' is not defined
```

Comment: is `outside(m)` in the same source file? if so, try putting it inside its own class. if not then make sure you reference the source file `sourceFile.FunctionName()`.

Comment: You could pass a reference to the function to the thread.

Comment: That should work as-is.  Are you running `ClientThread` within the namespace of your module?

Comment: I'm so sorry for silly question, but someone can offer some version of the code? 

P.s. nope, this method placed in main file (with class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that somewhere in the lump of omitted code between the definition of `ClientThread` and that of `outside`, you're creating and starting the client thread(s). At this point, your code will try to call `outside` and fail with the given error since the function has not been defined yet.

You should either start your thread(s) after defining `outside`, or move the definition of `outside` before `ClientThread`.

Comment: amazing) I just moved my method and it's work, ahahaha. It's a simply great!